# Vosk project unity cannot find libvosk

Tags: unity-game-engine, vosk

downloaded project with Vosk (Speech recognition system) implementation, and every project that i try  crashes, and in one project i found that error

DllNotFoundException: libvosk assembly: type: member:(null)
Vosk.Vosk.SetLogLevel (System.Int32 level) (at :0)
VoskSpeechToText+d__30.MoveNext () (at <51d31056a8e1447b80dc54febfe062d4>:0)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at :0)
i know it says dll not found but i know project has that dll and idk what i need to do to fix that issue

Im try to download few another project but they all has the same problem

Comment: Find the dll in your project and make sure it is enabled in the inspector for the platforms it supports.

Comment: How i can do that?)

Comment: You select the DLL in your project and look at the settings in the inspector. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html

Comment: I enabled it and got another error
DllNotFoundException: libvosk assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
Vosk.Model..ctor (System.String model_path) (at Assets/ThirdParty/Vosk/Model.cs:32)
VoskSpeechToText+<DoStartVoskStt>d__24.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/VoskSpeechToText.cs:138)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <5879d8d225474494bcffdfe64965038e>:0)

Comment: I try to enable platforms in dll again and project still crashes. May be we can go on discord, if its not difficult for you